# Partial differential equation directional derivatives

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm study PDE's because I find this interesting.

I know how to use directional derivatives to PDE's on two variables, but my problem is that I don't know how to deal with a PDE in three variables. For example this one
$$u_x+xu_y+yu_z=0$$
I know I can use method of characterization, but is it even possible to solve this PDE with directional derivatives?

Thanks in advance